# What ORM would you recommend?

Tags: c#, linq, oracle, orm

Here's my reqiurements:

1. Supports C#
2. Supports Oracle
3. Supports LINQ
4. Has ability to map business objects to database tables (not necessarily a 1-to-1 mapping)

I know an Oracle Entity Framework provider would support all these, but I've been told that making the custom mappings is not very easy.

What would you suggest?

Comment: I am looking to do the same research for my company. Unfortunately Oracle is treating .Net like a 2nd class citizen. It takes lot of resource to provide full EF compatibility and only Oracle can do that. Things like designer tools, POCO support, code only support, performance, transactions etc. Without the same level of features that Microsoft provides for SQL Server, Oracle will not gain mind and market share in .Net shops.
That being said I have done quick playing with Devart dotconnect for Oracle and simple LINQ worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use nHibernate. The linq support is coming. Not sure if its in their latest build or not but they just released a beta of their next release. It supports the rest of your requirements.

Comment: NHibernate.Linq 1.0 is already available at the "NHibernate Contrib" Project (http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that has native linq support as well as supporting all the features above, I'd have a look at [llblgen pro](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) or there's a new player called [Genome](http://www.genom-e.com/).

llblgen pro has been around for a long time and having used it on previous projects would recommend you check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried myself but you could try: http://devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/

Answer (score 1):

[SubSonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/). It's free and able to do all the things you've described.

Answer (score 1):

Half a vote for [Mindscape](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/) Lightspeed - a fine unit-of-work style cross-database ORM that works on Mono. They have some limited LINQ support at the moment with more in field test.

Answer (score 0):

Use ALinq, [www.alinq.org](http://www.alinq.org)